# Nexus (3.2) Base URL is ignored?

Tags: nginx, nexus

I can run Nexus 3.2.0-01 on my server at port 8081 without a problem, however I would like to run it as https://HOST/nexus/, reverse proxied through nginx.

According to the documentation, I need to set a Base URL capability, which I have.  I then added this to my nginx configuration:

```
location /nexus/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;

    # Rewrite HTTPS requests from WAN to HTTP requests on LAN                   
    proxy_redirect http:// https://;

    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
}
```

After doing so, I can access Nexus but no images load, the javascript doesn't load, etc.  Viewing Chrome's console, it looks like Nexus wants to access URLs such as:

```
https://HOST/static
https://HOST/service
https://HOST/repository
```

instead of:

```
https://HOST/nexus/static
https://HOST/nexus/service
https://HOST/nexus/repository
```

I can't find any way to configure Nexus to actually leverage the Base URL capability across the board.

I have tried:

- adding/removing the X-Forwarded-Proto
- setting location to ^~ /nexus/
- enabling and disabling the proxy_redirect

But no luck (not that I expected the generated URLs to reference /nexus based on the nginx configuration, I couldn't think of anything else to try).

Finally, I added proxy_passes for /static, /service, and /repository (assuming I'm not missing any) and at first glance it appears to work, though I haven't tried publishing or much else yet.

What am I doing wrong that Nexus won't use the Base URL properly?

Comment: Did you figured this out?

Answer (score 6):

In case you are runnig a Dockerized version of nexus3 behind nginx (or other reverse proxy) you can use the environment variable NEXUS_CONTEXT to set the new context.

For example in my docker compose:

```
nexus:
   image: sonatype/nexus3:3.11.0
   ports:
     - 8081:8081
   networks:
     - my_net
   environment:
      NEXUS_CONTEXT: nexus
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run Nexus on a context path other than "/" you must adjust the context path Nexus is actually running on.  Edit "sonatype-work/nexus3/etc/nexus.properties and set "nexus-context-path=/nexus".  See here for our other recommendations:

http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/index.html

Comment: The book (from your link) for version 3 has no mention of nexus-context-path, in section 2.7 it says to just use the Base URL Capability to make this change.  I will give this one a try later today and report back!

Comment: This is what you need: http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/install.html#config-context-path

Comment: Updated documentation: https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/install.html#config-context-path

Comment: Link is dead. Correct link https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/installation/configuring-the-runtime-environment#ConfiguringtheRuntimeEnvironment-ChangingtheContextPath

Comment: Thanks @rseddon.  You saved me a lot of time.  I don't see why Nexus doesn't mention this anywhere in the page: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/installation/run-behind-a-reverse-proxy

Answer (score 1):

The base path should match for both, nginx and nexus. For this to work, you should change the nexus-context-path on nexus.properties by setting the ENV NEXUS_CONTEXT.

I have deployed nexus on Kubernetes using its Helm chart, but it should be practically the same.

If you are using the helm [chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/sonatype-nexus), you can add this to your values.yaml

```
nexus:
  env:
    - name: NEXUS_CONTEXT
      value: nexus
```

Here is the full values.yaml

```
sonatype-nexus:
  statefulset:
    enabled: true
  nexusProxy:
    env:
      nexusDockerHost: mydocker.example.com
      nexusHttpHost: mynexus.example.com
      additionalNexusHost: mynexus3.example.com
  nexus:
    env:
      - name: install4jAddVmParams
        value: "-Xms1200M -Xmx1200M -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap"
      - name: NEXUS_CONTEXT
        value: nexus
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 3
        memory: 5Gi
      requests:
        cpu: 250m
        memory: 4Gi
    readinessProbe:
      path: /nexus
    livenessProbe:
      path: /nexus
    service:
      type: ClusterIP
    securityContext:
      fsGroup: 2000
  persistence:
    storageClass: ssd
    storageSize: 20Gi
  ingress:
    enabled: false
```

I disabled the Helm chart ingress for my convenience, but you can use it if you want to. Nevertheless, here is how my ingress looks:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
  labels:
    app: sonatype-nexus
    heritage: Tiller
    release: nexus
  name: nexus-sonatype-nexus
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mynexus.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: nexus-sonatype-nexus
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /nexus
  - host: mynexus3.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: nexus-sonatype-nexus
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /nexus
  - host: mydocker.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: nexus-sonatype-nexus
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - mynexus.example.com
    - mydocker.example.com
    - mynexus3.example.com
    secretName: wildcard-example-com
```

Comment: can you share your full vaules.yaml? I can't handle this.

Comment: @hokwang sorry for the delay, here are the full values.yaml I used.